# Unable to install OSSEC - Error: pcre2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, redhat, pcre, ossec, pcre2

I am trying to install OSSEC on my linux server OS Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga), and PCRE is a requirement. I have already downloaded the files for OSSEC v3.7.0 and PCRE2 v10.37, but when trying to install I get the error:

> In file included from ./headers/shared.h:215, from client-agent/agentd.c:10:
> ./os_regex/os_regex.h:19:19: error: pcre2.h: No such file or directory
> In file included from ./headers/shared.h:215, from client-agent/agentd.c:10:
> ./os_regex/os_regex.h:47: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre2_code’
> ./os_regex/os_regex.h:57: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre2_code’
> ./os_regex/os_regex.h:68: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre2_code’
> make: *** [client-agent/agentd.o] Error 1
> Error 0x5.
> Building error. Unable to finish the installation.

This is what I did:

> ossec-hids-3.7.0]#mv ../pcre2-10.37.tar.gz .
> ossec-hids-3.7.0]#tar -zxvf pcre2-10.37.tar.gz -C src/external/
> ossec-hids-3.7.0]#sudo PCRE2_SYSTEM=yes ./install.sh

Should pcre.h be as a file on my zip folder? Because I did not find it there.
Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You need `pcre-devel`:

```
$ dnf whatprovides */pcre2.h
[..]
pcre2-devel-10.32-2.el8.i686 : Development files for pcre2
Repo        : baseos
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/pcre2.h

pcre2-devel-10.32-2.el8.x86_64 : Development files for pcre2
Repo        : baseos
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/pcre2.h
```